# Parse txt file using Twig

Tags: php, parsing, symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 with twig in it and I have large files (>100MB), which I want to parse and write some information from it into the HTML page.
If I use my own Twig extension I get a memory exhaustion error. So is there a way to parse txt file straight from the twig file?

small file example:

```
1
003.00 001.00 
000.00 005.00
```

result in HTML:

```
3+x+5xy
```

Comment: Hey H.W.  Could you provide the code you use to read and output the text file. Also please note that Twig is a templating language. You are doing file reading now. That looks like the wrong way.

Comment: As Design consideration, i suggest you to treat the file as storage and access to it via a (sort of, not doctrine) repository. So do the work in the controller (better if the controller call a dedicated service) and return it to the view (twig)

Comment: mvbrakel I don't have the code yet. But I'm afraid if I load the whole file and give it to the Twig template I get memeory error, if the file is large.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a custom extension and using a generator? (http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)